# Excel VBA - copy text between cells, and modify text

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am a VBA novice trying to create a sub that copies a text to the next empty cell to the right and increments any number in the text by 1. I thought the following sub would do, but it gives me really weird and unexpected results. Can someone pls advise where I went wrong? thanks for all and any input

```
Sub runheading()
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim text As String, str As String

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("a1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 64
    Selection = Selection.Offset(0, -1)

    text = Selection
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(text, i, 1)) Then
            str = str & Mid(text, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    For j = 1 To Len(text)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(text, i, 1)) Then
            j = Mid(text, i, 1)            
        End If
    Next j

    Selection = str & (j + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: *but it gives me really weird and unexpected results*. Please, be more specific. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. It copies the text element just fine, but instead of incrementing the number by 1 it goes straight from 12 (my first entry) to 15 and then repeats 15 for all the next entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

just added the text searching.

```
Private Sub runheading()


  Dim row As Integer
  Dim column As Integer

  column = 1
  row = 1


  Do While column < 10

    'first find the free cell to the right
    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, column))
        column = column + 1
        Loop

    'After that take the further left cell Value and write it into the targeted empty cell
  Dim text As String
  Dim str As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim number As Integer
      text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, column - 1).Value

      For i = 1 To Len(text)
        If IsNumeric(Right(text, i)) Then
            number = Right(text, i)
            str = Left(text, Len(text) - i)
        Else: End If
        Next i


      Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, column).Value = str & (number + 1)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: Now it works perfectly - just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear :)

Comment: If this works for you, please mark the answer as accepted, so that other users can find it, in case they are looking for a similar solution :)

Comment: For my own learning: can you please explain the purpose of the  "Do While collumn < 10" at the start of the sub? I understand the rest, but not that bit. Thanks! David

Comment: I limited the Collumns just to prevent the tool from breaking. Without the do while the script would write up to the last row and break because of an overflow.

If you set the do while to 30 it would write 30 Collumns to the right.